Input Parameters for Combustion Chamber
I am doing a column breakup study. But for a better study I need air velocity, turbulence intensity (not primarily needed though),temperature, pressure and same parameter for injected liquid fuel. I searched for an commercials but there is no useful information. Could you help me with the sources ?
Thank you in advance.

Engineering or chemistry stackexchange may be better place for your question

I've posted it. Thank you
